# ESLint: fromEvent is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';

const touchstart = (input) => Observable.merge(
    Observable.fromEvent(input, 'pointerdown')
      .filter(event => event.pointerType === 'touch'),
    Observable.fromEvent(input, 'touchstart'));
```

I'm getting the following linting error:
    ESLint: fromEvent is defined but never used (no-unused-vars)

and the same on `merge`. The problem is that I need to import `fromEvent` and `merge` otherwise it doesn't include them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try just importing these modules, without assigning them to anything:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/merge';
```